# List Multi-Sorting

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list that I would like to sort in multiple ways.

My List is made using this:

```
theMainList.Add(new LoadLine(theChipList[count].Name, theChipList[count].PartNumber, 
                theChipList[count].XPlacement, theChipList[count].YPlacement, 
                theChipList[count].Rotation, theChipList[count].PkgStyle, 
                theChipList[count].PackageType, theChipList[count].PartDescription,
                theChipList[count].Feeder, theChipList[count].Vision,
                theChipList[count].Speed, theChipList[count].Machine,
                theChipList[count].TapeWidth, theChipList[count].PlacingTime));
```

I start off by getting each line using `foreach(var line in theMainList)`.

Now, for each `line` I need to compare certain positions and sort them accordingly.

So, **FIRST** what I would like to compare is each `line.Speed` and organize the list numerically *(so if the speeds were 1,2,3,4,5, etc the first line in the list would be the line that has the `line.Speed` equal to 1, and then 2, etc.)*

**SECOND** I would like to sort the updated list that is now in order of `line.Speed` again. I would like to sort the `line.PackageStyle` in the order of this:

```
"FIDUCIAL", "FID", "FID0", "FID1", "FID2", "FID3", "FID4", "FID5",
"FID6", "FID7", "FID8", "FID9", "RES", "0402", "0201", "0603", 
"0805","1206", "1306", "1608", "3216", "2551", "1913", "1313",
"2513","5125", "2525", "5619", "3813", "1508", "6431", "2512",
"1505","2208", "1005", "1010", "2010", "0505", "0705", "1020",
"1812","2225", "5764", "4532", "1210", "0816", "0363", "SOT"
```

**THIRD** I would like to sort the new updated list with the `Speed` sorted first, and then thee `PackageStyle` sorted secondly...by the `line.PartNumber`.  Again this would be numerically just like the `line.Speed` was.

Is there any way to do this mulitple sorting technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Linq's [`OrderBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) and [`ThenBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) methods:

```
theMainList.OrderBy(l => l.Speed)
           .ThenBy(l => l.PackageStyle)
           .ThenBy(l => l.PartNumber);
```

Comment: This does not seem to be sorting it properly.. I have a DataGridView bound to a List and it is not sorting the DataGridView when I update the List?

Comment: @theNoobGuy - these methods return a sorted list, they do not sort the original list.  You will need to re-bind your DataGridView to the sorted list.

Comment: Would I do that by simply writing: `mainDGV.DataSource = sortedList;`.. or is there something else I need to do because this does not seem to be working properly.

Comment: @theNoobGuy - Remember to also do `mainDGV.DataBind()` after you set the sorted list as the DataSource.

Comment: What is the context?  Is this Windows Forms?  ASP.Net?

Comment: Windows Forms using Visual Studio 2010 C#

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this using the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` extension methods available in the `System.Linq` namespace.  E.g.,

```
var sortedList = theMainList
   .OrderBy(l => l.Speed)
   .ThenBy(l => l.PackageStyle)
   .ThenBy(l => l.PartNumber);
```

Keep in mind you might need to override the default comparisons using IComparer.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @Iasaac: This does not seem to be sorting it properly.. I have a DataGridView bound to a List and it is not sorting the DataGridView when I update the List?

Comment: Updated.  `OrderBy` doesn't operate on the list, it returns an `IOrderedEnumerable` representing the sorted list.

Comment: I tried adding this to set the DataSource of the DGV: `mainDGV.DataSource = sortedList;`? However, this does not seem to work.. am I missing something else that I need to add?